# jQuery UI Draggable 1.10.3 issue with Firefox not finding cursor center when window is scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Prior to 1.10.3, I think it was 1.9.x, I did not have this issue.  However after the update to jQuery UI 1.10.3, Firefox is having issues with finding the cursor center on the draggable plugin when the window is scrolled down.

This does not happen in Chrome, Safari or IE...

Have you guys seen this before?

```
var itemImageTop = parseInt( $( 'ul li img' ).attr( 'height' ), 10 ) / 2,
    itemImageLeft = parseInt( $( 'ul li img' ).attr( 'width' ), 10 ) / 2;

$( 'ul li img' ).draggable( {
    appendTo:   'body',
    helper:     'clone',
    opacity:    0.5,
    zIndex:     100001,
    cursor:     'move',
    cursorAt:   { top: itemImageTop, left: itemImageLeft },    
} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hjgy6/

When you run the script, scroll the preview window down with the scroll bar and then try dragging the image.  You will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok having searched high and low, I finally found out that this is a bug...due to be fixed in 1.11.x

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9315

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, I was just having this exact issue and only in Firefox, and it ends up that the way that I corrected it was by adding `position:relative;` to the container element that was holding my draggable elements.  I just wanted to put this here in case anyone else comes across this as I tried every single hack under the sun I could figure out, and it wasn't until I just started tinkering with the position attributes that I was able to get it to work.  Probably won't work for everyone, but might help someone!

Comment: I too found that by adding "position: relative" (in my case, to the body element) that it fixed this issue.

Comment: Adding "position:relative" to the container element worked perfect for me in Firefox 25.0.1. Thanks!